# possibility of adding gtalk contacts to my whatsapp

Tags: applications, contacts, sync, google-talk

Could I bring my gtalk contacts to link to my Whatsapp? (in other words Sync the two?)

I don't want to run two seperate apps and wondering if there was a possibility to add these together? I will only be using Whatsapp now so really really need to hopefully be able to bring those in gtalk to link to it... any advice please??

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It's not possible. A key reason for this is (at least) that

- GTalk identifies people with email address while
- WhatsApp identifies people by their mobile number.

On top of this both of the systems are proprietary and I don't think neither Google nor WhatsApp would want their users to be pushed over to the other system.

The above said, if you have the mobile number(s) of your GTalk contacts then those will, of course, be added to WhatsApp automatically if they also use WhatsApp. But that's really just stating the obvious.